# Android: two tasks - two launcher icons

Tags: android-activity, icons, launcher

I have an activity A (i want that work in background) that start activity B with code

```
moveTaskToBack(false);
Intent intent = new Intent(context.getActivity(), BActivity.class); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );  
startActivity(intent);
```

In manifest i have

```
<activity android:name="ru.nekit.BActivity"                 
 android:label="B"              
 android:taskAffinity="ru.nekit"/>
```

When start activity B and press Home button i see that there is two launcher icons
Question how can i do that wiil be only one launche icon?

Answer (score 2):

Your app may have multiple activities found in your launcher based upon your manifest file and the XML attribute:

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

For each activity that you list containing this attribute, you will have another icon found within the Launcher for that activity. Make sure you only have this attribute set for the activity you want to display in the launcher.

You may also have installed multiple versions of your app when developing if you ended up changing the application name somewhere along the way. Be sure to uninstall all previous versions.